# Can someone explain HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token")

Tags: identityserver4

I have implemented an ASP.NET Core MVC Client using Hybrid flow, and I am wondering what the HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token") does.

## If you need more background on my question:

The instructions for accessing an API from with an ASP.Net Core Client App Controller Action are generally as follows:

```
var accessToken = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
var client = new HttpClient();
client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:5001/api/stuff");
```

There is magic in httpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token") :-)

I am wondering what this function might be doing. Is it decrypting the access token from a cookie in the MVC App Domain? ... from the ID4 Domain?

I am sorry but I have been unable to find sufficient documentation on what this does or finding the cookie the access token may be in. I have looked here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationtokenextensions

Does anyone know what it does? A link to more thorough documentation is a totally appreciated answer.

TU!

Comment: What do you have in your startup calls where you call 'services.AddAuthentication()'?

Comment: @aaronR Honestly, I have no idea - I had to look at the source code definition of `AddAuthentication` to see what it does. Confounding things, `AddIdentityServer` and `AddMvc` both call `AddAuthentication` too! (and I'd have had no idea without looking at their source code as it isn't well documented). This is why I'm not a fan of the "builder"/"fluent" style for configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can store arbitrary tokens in your authentication cookie in and that method simply returns one with a given name. Actually setting that would have happened during the sign in process. So in short, it comes from the authentication cookie for your *client* application and would typically be set at the point of sign in using IdSrv4.

Answer (score 1):

It's a way for the client webapp to confirm separately whether the user really did authenticate with IdentityServer (the user comes to your webapp, the webapp forwards the user to IdentityServer for authentication).  The id_token comes back with the user to your webapp in a browser cookie, basically when your webapp sees that id token, it does an independent check with IdentityServer, and if it represents a valid user authentication, you'll get an access token back.  You can use that access token to get user claims from the userinfo endpoint.

After all of the above, you can take one of the claims and use it as a key for your application's roles/permissions.